# How execute fuction sum() in a column with df concate with other df

Tags: python, pandas, sum, concatenation

I am using concat to merge 5 equal df into one and get the total sum() of cost.

These values are not real, just an example of what df looks like

What I tried:

```py
import pandas as pd

g = {"id": "1515", "cost": "100"}
b = {"id": "1515", "cost": "100"}
f = {"id": "1515", "cost": "100"}
c = {"id": "1515", "cost": "100"}
o = {"id": "1515", "cost": "100"}

all_vendors = pd.concat([g, b, f, c, o])
```

Data types

```
all_vendors.dtypes

Campaign          object
campaignid       float64
Campaign_name     object
Cost              object
Month             object
Year & month      object
dtype: object
```

Attempts

Attempt #1:

```
all_vendors.Cost.sum()
```

Results in:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Attempt #2:

```
all_vendors.Cost.astype(str)
all_vendors.Cost.sum()
```

Results in:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Attempt #3:

```
all_vendors.Cost.astype(float)
all_vendors.Cost.sum()
```

Results in:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '100'

Comment: g,b,f,c,o are dataframe or dict?

Comment: Data frames, it just example

Comment: Your first code doesnt run ...https://repl.it/repls/GlisteningIntentCode

Comment: Thanks @Peter,please  check my answer :)

Comment: This will work if you have commas in your string.  `all_vendors['cost'].map(lambda x: x.replace(",","")).astype('float').sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not reassigning your `astype` call back to your `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "id": ['1,515','1,515','1,515','1,515','1,515'],
  "cost": ['1,000','1,000','1,000','1,000','1,000']
}

all_vendors = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

all_vendors['cost'] = all_vendors.cost.str.replace(',','').astype(float)
print(all_vendors.cost.sum())
# Output: 500
```

As mentioned in the comments, use `str.replace` to remove any commas you have in your strings

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,929.40'

Thanks for helping. something mid be weird with my data

Comment: @Peter Try `all_vendors['cost'].map(lambda x: x.replace(",","")).astype('float').sum()`

Comment: why map to replace? why not `all_vendors['cost'].str.replace(',','').astype('float').sum()`?

Comment: @Peter it just doesn't like the commas

Comment: @Nick Martin thanks, I found out the problem. you're right.
one of the spreed sheets I was using had commas on it. I just removed manually and now works

Answer (score 1):

you first need to convert dataframe to float to be able to add numbers with decimals, for them you use [`DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```
import pandas as pd
g = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["1515"], "cost": ["100"]})
b = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["1515"], "cost": ["100"]})
f = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["1515"], "cost": ["100"]})
c = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["1515"], "cost": ["100"]})
o = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["1515"], "cost": ["100"]})
all_vendors = pd.concat([g, b, f, c, o])
```

---

**if you have ',' in your string, then you need:**

```
all_vendors['cost']=all_vendors['cost'].str.replace(',','')
```

Then you calculate the sum:

```
all_vendors.astype(float).cost.sum()
```

Output:

```
500.0
```

**if you want to work with the float type data frame you need to assign it:**

```
all_vendors2=all_vendors.astype(float)
all_vendros2.cost.sum()
```

Output:

```
500
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work on my end with a value of 500:

```
df_list = [pd.DataFrame(data={"id": ["1515"], "cost": ["100"]}) for i in range(5)]
pd.concat(df_list).cost.astype(float).sum()
```

So long as they're dataframes and you convert the strings to floats, it looks good.

Comment: TypeError: 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
 Thanks for helping, some thing went weird

Answer (score 1):

Check if this helps.This will give total of id's.

```
import pandas as pd

g = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["1515"], "cost": ["100"]})
b = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["1515"], "cost": ["100"]})
f = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["1515"], "cost": ["100"]})
c = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["1515"], "cost": ["100"]})
o = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["1515"], "cost": ["100"]})
all_vendors = pd.concat([g, b, f, c, o])

a=pd.DataFrame.from_records(all_vendors).astype(float).groupby('id').sum().T.to_dict()
print(a)
```

Comment: Why do you need the `groupby`?

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Lower Funnel'